# Only show items that are not in other table laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to only show the schools that are not favorited.

to get the ones favorited I use:

```
 $favorite_schools = DB::table('favorite_schools')
                            ->select('favorite_schools.*', 'schools.name')
                            ->leftJoin('schools', 'schools.id', 'favorite_schools.school_id')
                            ->get();
```

Schools table:

```
Schema::create('schools', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('active');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Favorite_schools table:

```
 Schema::create('favorite_schools', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('school_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

How can I only get the schools that have not been favorited yet?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel syntax, but in general, to find rows that don't have a row in a related table, you want an outer join where the joined table is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go the other way. Get the schools, and left join on the favorites table, then get the results that does not have a result in the favorite_schools table.

```
$favorite_schools = DB::table('schools')
                        ->select('schools.name', 'schools.id')
                        ->leftJoin('favorite_schools', 'schools.id', 'favorite_schools.school_id')
                        ->whereNull('favorite_schools.school_id')
                        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `WhereNull('favorite_schools.school_id')` to the query you use to get the favorite ones. that will give you the not favorite schools.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

a slightly different approach would be to use `whereNotExists`

usage would be something like this:

```
$schools = DB::table('schools')
    ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
              ->from('favorite_schools')
              ->whereRaw('favorite_schools.school_id = school.id');
    })
    ->get();
```